# Need <p> to fill height of <div> parrent

Tags: html, css, web

My over all goal is to center vertically some text. Right now i have a div containing a p.
The div is:

```
.container{
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 height: auto;
 min-height: 100px;
 border: 1px solid red;
 width: 60%;
 overflow: hidden;
 }
```

and the p:

```
.welcome_title{
 float: left;
 width: 30%;
 height: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
 font-size: 200%;
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-align: center;
 }
```

What this does is make the p's height 100% of the screen and not its parrent. Any Help?

Comment: add `position:relative` to `.container`

Comment: The vertical-align property only works on table-cell or inline elements, a floated element is neither.  Also, *welcome_title* doesn't sound very paragraphy, it sounds like a headline...

Comment: _Does_ that "make the p's height 100% of the screen"? http://jsfiddle.net/RUUVy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **vertical-align** property will not work unless you use **display: table-cell**

Don't know why your welcome_title is floated left and if the float is needed, but here you will find three examples. I'm sure you will find one that suits your need.

http://deeson-online.co.uk/labs/how-centre-align-text-or-content-vertically-css

Comment: One more question.. is it possible to make the table cells dynamic?